# Determine that a particular file is in fact a 3gp file

Tags: c++

I do scanning of file system and I need identify all 3gp files.

Usually, for noting that particular file is of certain format, developers of that format make  marks.

E.g.  first bytes of  FLV are 46 4C 56 01, if it's so, one can be sure that this is FLV format (if no one changed it intentionally, of course), etc.

I'd be glad to identify 3gp files in the same way, but which bytes do indicate that?

Comment: I suggest looking to see if the unix command `file` can identify 3GP files, and if so, how it does it (I believe it uses a similar approach to what you mention).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: The full specifications can be found somewhere in here: http://www.3gpp.org/specifications

Comment: @Blorgbeard, thanks, but what if I find a file with such signature, which extension should I give it 3GG or 3GP or  3G2 ?

Comment: @gekannt: its fairly self explanatory.  Did you actually look at the entry to see the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
00 00 00 nn 66 74 79 70 33 67 70
```

`nn` is `14` for 3GPP files and `20` for 3GPP2 ones.

All hail Wikipedia.

Comment: @gekannt 3GPP is the name. 3GP is the file extension. You know, like JPG for JPEG files.

Comment: IIRC, nn is the length of the box which can vary and so this solution won't always work

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the `ftyp` box

[More here, see the 'File Type Box' section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_12)